# Norm of the resolvent of the right shift operator on $\ell^2$

Tags: hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces, spectral-theory

Let $S$ be the right shift operator on $\ell^2$, that is,
$$Sx=y,\ x=(\xi_1,\xi_2,\cdots),\ y=(0,\xi_1,\xi_2,\cdots).$$
Then it is OK that $||S||=1$. For $a\in\Bbb C$ with $|a|>1$, then $a\in \rho(S)$, and how can we prove that 
$$||(a I-S)^{-1}||=(|a|-1)^{-1}.$$

Clearly, if $(aI-S)^{-1}x=y$, then $$||x||=||(aI-S)y||
>=|a| ||y||-||Sy||=(|a|-1)||y||.$$ From this, we know 
$$||(a I-S)^{-1}||\leq (|a|-1)^{-1}.$$ 
Now hwo can I have prove that $$||(a I-S)^{-1}||>=(|a|-1)^{-1}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $y=(1,\lambda,\cdots,\lambda^n,\cdots)$ where $|\lambda|<1$. One may immediately check that $y=\lambda Sy+(1,0,0,\cdots)$. Hence $(aI-S)y=ay-Sy=(a\lambda-1)Sy+(a,0,0,\cdots)$. As a consequence, 
$$|a\lambda-1|\cdot\|y\|-|a|\leq\|(aI-S)y\|\leq |a\lambda-1|\cdot\|y\|+|a|$$ 
Let $x=(aI-S)y$. Since $\|y\|$ can be arbitrarily large(just take $|\lambda|\to 1^-$), the above inequality implies that $\|x\|$ can be arbitrarily large, while $\|(aI-S)^{-1}x\|\geq|a\lambda-1|^{-1}\|x\|-|a|/|a\lambda-1|$. Hence
$$\|(aI-S)^{-1}\|\geq|a\lambda-1|^{-1}-\frac{|a|}{|a\lambda-1|\cdot\|x\|}$$
Now choose appropriate $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $ae^{i\theta}=|a|$. Take $\lambda=re^{i\theta}$ and let $r\to 1^-$. The condition $|a|>1$ is applied so that $|a\lambda-1|$ won't be zero as $r\to 1^-$.